# How to list all block contents drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

How can i list all custom block contents in block layout page without click on place block in drupal 8.Please let me know if any module is available.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created one context for the custom block. But its not working. :( .As it is drupal default settings to list down the block contents after being placed to a region, so dont know how to list it. My aim is to list the newly created block content with hidden region.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].